# Private inheritance using directive, overloads?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm using private inheritance in a project, in the "implemented in terms of"-sense. The base class defines operator[], and this is the functionality I want to use. Thus, I have

```
class A : private B {
    using B::operator[];
    // ...
};
```

However, how can I control which version of the operator[] I get? In fact, I need more than one, both the `const` and non-`const` versions. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: In this case you could use composition to give you the desired result instead of private inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, I know... I changed it to private inheritance instead to reduce the amount of forwarding code. So it's not possible? How is the function acually chosen?

Comment: Your code will be much easier to write and maintain if you use composition instead of private inheritance here.  The rule of thumb is to not use off-the-wall features of C++ when they are not absolutely necessary (from what you've said so far, private inheritance is not necessary in this case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that your `using` should automatically bring in all the different overloads of the operator. Are there certain overloads you want to exclude from being brought into the child class? In that case it might be better to split the work into several differently named functions in the parent and only `using` the ones you need.

Comment: I'd have thought so too, but I get compile errors from const-discarding, despite there being versions returning both `T&` and `const T&` (template typename T)

Comment: So, this is one of them "magically fixed itself" times... After looking up and down the code and recompiling, it suddenly works, and I can't for the life of me understand what I changed. What did change though is I learned a little bit more about inheritance, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This does as expected:

```
class A
{
public:
  int operator[](int idx) { return 0; }
  int operator[](int idx) const { return 1; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  using A::operator[];

  void opa() { cout << operator[](1) << endl; }
  void opb() const { cout << operator[](1) << endl; }
};

int main(void)
{
  B b;
  b.opa();
  b.opb();

  const B d = B();
  cout << d[1] << endl; // should trigger the const version of operator[]
  return 0;
}
```

In another words, the appropriate const/non const versions are injected into `B`. NOTE: If the const version is not provided, then you will receive a compiler error (this works whether the inheritance is private or public).

Comment: I would also add `b[2];` or similar to `main` to show that the operator functions can be used directly from outside `class B`.